# An iframe suddenly appeared after Login and disabled all the screen

Tags: html, reactjs, iframe, google-identity

I'm developing a React application, using Facebook and Google login.

When I start my application the following `iframe` suddenly appears as the latest instruction of my `index.html` file:

```html
<iframe style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; z-index: 2147483647;"></iframe>
```

As can be noted, the `iframe` is empty, but occupy the entire screen, with a really high `z-index`, and this set put it on top on every other object on the screen, effectively  preventing the user to interact with the application.

My opinion is that this `iframe` would be generated by google if something doesn't like them about the application settings.

This is the initial part of the `iframe` body, as someone could recognize it; as you can see, there are strange unicode characters too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">/*! For license information please see iframe-bundle.js.LICENSE.txt */
(()=>{var e={5270:e=>{e.exports=function(e,t){(null==t||t>e.length)&&(t=e.length);for(var r=0,n=new Array(t);r<t;r++)n[r]=e[r];return n},e.exports.default=e.exports,e.exports.__esModule=!0},3041:(e,t,r)=>{var n=r(6487);e.exports=function(e,t){var r="undefined"!==typeof Symbol&&e[Symbol.iterator]||e["@@iterator"];if(!r){if(Array.isArray(e)||(r=n(e))||t&&e&&"number"===typeof e.length){r&&(e=r);var o=0,a=function(){};return{s:a,n:function(){return o>=e.length?{done:!0}:{done:!1,value:e[o++]}},e:function(e){throw e},f:a}}throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance.\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.")}var i,l=!0,u=!1;return{s:function(){r=r.call(e)},n:function(){var e=r.next();return l=e.done,e},e:function(e){u=!0,i=e},f:function(){try{l||null==r.return||r.return()}finally{if(u)throw i}}}},e.exports.default=e.exports,e.exports.__esModule=!0},6487:(e,t,r)=>{var n=r(5270);e.exports=function(e,t){if(e){if("string"===typeof e)return n(e,t);var r=Object.prototype.toString.call(e).slice(8,-1);return"Object"===r&&e.constructor&&(r=e.constructor.name),"Map"===r||"Set"===r?Array.from(e):"Arguments"===r||/^(?:Ui|I)nt(?:8|16|32)(?:Clamped)?Array$/.test(r)?n(e,t):void 0}},e.exports.default=e.exports,e.exports.__esModule=!0},7162:(e,t,r)=>{e.exports=r(2205)},8641:(e,t,r)=>{"use strict";t.rf=u;var n=r(8048),o=!1;function a(e){return{gutter:e.grey,marker:e.red.bold,message:e.red.bold}}var i=/\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029]/;function l(e,t,r){var n=Object.assign({column:0,line:-1},e.start),o=Object.assign({},n,e.end),a=r||{},i=a.linesAbove,l=void 0===i?2:i,u=a.linesBelow,s=void 0===u?3:u,c=n.line,f=n.column,d=o.line,p=o.column,h=Math.max(c-(l+1),0),g=Math.min(t.length,d+s);-1===c&&(h=0),-1===d&&(g=t.length);var m=d-c,v={};if(m)for(var y=0;y<=m;y++){var b=y+c;if(f)if(0===y){var w=t[b-1].length;v[b]=[f,w-f+1]}else if(y===m)v[b]=[0,p];else{var x=t[b-y].length;v[b]=[0,x]}else v[b]=!0}else v[c]=f===p?!f||[f,0]:[f,p-f];return{start:h,end:g,markerLines:v}}function u(e,t){var r=arguments.length>2&&void 0!==arguments[2]?arguments[2]:{},o=(r.highlightCode||r.forceColor)&&(0,n.shouldHighlight)(r),u=(0,n.getChalk)(r),s=a(u),c=function(e,t){return o?e(t):t},f=e.split(i),d=l(t,f,r),p=d.start,h=d.end,g=d.markerLines,m=t.start&&"number"===typeof t.start.column,v=String(h).length,y=o?(0,n.default)(e,r):e,b=y.split(i,h).slice(p,h).map((function(e,t){var n=p+1+t,o=" ".concat(n).slice(-v),a=" ".concat(o," |"),i=g[n],l=!g[n+1];if(i){var u="";if(Array.isArray(i)){var f=e.slice(0,Math.max(i[0]-1,0)).replace(/[^\t]/g," "),d=i[1]||1;u=["\n ",c(s.gutter,a.replace(/\d/g," "))," ",f,c(s.marker,"^").repeat(d)].join(""),l&&r.message&&(u+=" "+c(s.message,r.message))}return[c(s.marker,">"),c(s.gutter,a),e.length>0?" ".concat(e):"",u].join("")}return" ".concat(c(s.gutter,a)).concat(e.length>0?" ".concat(e):"")})).join("\n");return r.message&&!m&&(b="".concat(" ".repeat(v+1)).concat(r.message,"\n").concat(b)),o?u.reset(b):b}},1714:(e,t)=>{"use strict";Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",{value:!0}),t.isIdentifierStart=s,t.isIdentifierChar=c,t.isIdentifierName=function(e){for(var t=!0,r=0;r<e.length;r++){var n=e.charCodeAt(r);if(55296===(64512&n)&&r+1<e.length){var o=e.charCodeAt(++r);56320===(64512&o)&&(n=65536+((1023&n)<<10)+(1023&o))}if(t){if(t=!1,!s(n))return!1}else if(!c(n))return!1}return!t};var r="ªµºÀ-ÖØ-öø-ˁˆ-ˑˠ-ˤˬˮͰ-ʹͶͷͺ-ͽͿΆΈ-ΊΌΎ-ΡΣ-ϵϷ-ҁҊ-ԯԱ-Ֆՙՠ-ֈא-תׯ-ײؠ-يٮٯٱ-ۓەۥۦۮۯۺ-ۼۿܐܒ-ܯݍ-ޥޱߊ-ߪߴߵߺࠀ-ࠕࠚࠤࠨࡀ-ࡘࡠ-ࡪࡰ-ࢇࢉ-ࢎࢠ-ࣉऄ-हऽॐक़-ॡॱ-ঀঅ-ঌএঐও-নপ-রলশ-হঽৎড়ঢ়য়-ৡৰৱৼਅ-ਊਏਐਓ-ਨਪ-ਰਲਲ਼ਵਸ਼ਸਹਖ਼-ੜਫ਼ੲ-ੴઅ-ઍએ-ઑઓ-નપ-રલળવ-હઽૐૠૡૹଅ-ଌଏଐଓ-ନପ-ରଲଳଵ-ହଽଡ଼ଢ଼ୟ-ୡୱஃஅ-ஊஎ-ஐஒ-கஙசஜஞடணதந-பம-ஹௐఅ-ఌఎ-ఐఒ-నప-హఽౘ-ౚౝౠౡಀಅ-ಌಎ-ಐಒ-ನಪ-ಳವ-ಹಽೝೞೠೡೱೲഄ-ഌഎ-ഐഒ-ഺഽൎൔ-ൖൟ-ൡൺ-ൿඅ-ඖක-නඳ-රලව-ෆก-ะาำเ-ๆກຂຄຆ-ຊຌ-ຣລວ-ະາຳຽເ-ໄໆໜ-ໟༀཀ-ཇཉ-ཬྈ-ྌက-ဪဿၐ-ၕၚ-ၝၡၥၦၮ-ၰၵ-ႁႎႠ-ჅჇჍა-ჺჼ-ቈቊ-ቍቐ-ቖቘቚ-ቝበ-ኈኊ-ኍነ-ኰኲ-ኵኸ-ኾዀዂ-ዅወ-ዖዘ-ጐጒ-ጕጘ-ፚᎀ-ᎏᎠ-Ᏽᏸ-ᏽᐁ-ᙬᙯ-ᙿᚁ-ᚚᚠ-ᛪᛮ-ᛸᜀ-ᜑᜟ-ᜱᝀ-ᝑᝠ-ᝬᝮ-ᝰក-ឳៗៜᠠ-ᡸᢀ-ᢨᢪᢰ-ᣵᤀ-ᤞᥐ-ᥭᥰ-ᥴᦀ-ᦫᦰ-ᧉᨀ-ᨖᨠ-ᩔᪧᬅ-ᬳᭅ-ᭌᮃ-ᮠᮮᮯᮺ-ᯥᰀ-ᰣᱍ-ᱏᱚ-ᱽᲀ-ᲈᲐ-ᲺᲽ-Ჿᳩ-ᳬᳮ-ᳳᳵᳶᳺᴀ-ᶿḀ-ἕἘ-Ἕἠ-ὅὈ-Ὅὐ-ὗὙὛὝὟ-ώᾀ-ᾴᾶ-ᾼιῂ-ῄῆ-ῌῐ-ΐῖ-Ίῠ-Ῥῲ-ῴῶ-ῼⁱⁿₐ-ₜℂℇℊ-ℓℕ℘-ℝℤΩℨK-ℹℼ-ℿⅅ-ⅉⅎⅠ-ↈⰀ-ⳤⳫ-ⳮⳲⳳⴀ-ⴥⴧⴭⴰ-ⵧⵯⶀ-ⶖⶠ-ⶦⶨ-ⶮⶰ-ⶶⶸ-ⶾⷀ-ⷆⷈ-ⷎⷐ-ⷖⷘ-ⷞ々-〇〡-〩〱-〵〸-〼ぁ-ゖ゛-ゟァ-ヺー-ヿㄅ-ㄯㄱ-ㆎㆠ-ㆿㇰ-ㇿ㐀-䶿一-ꒌꓐ-ꓽꔀ-ꘌꘐ-ꘟꘪꘫꙀ-ꙮꙿ-ꚝꚠ-ꛯꜗ-ꜟꜢ-ꞈꞋ-ꟊꟐꟑꟓꟕ-ꟙꟲ-ꠁꠃ-ꠅꠇ-ꠊꠌ-ꠢꡀ-ꡳꢂ-ꢳꣲ-ꣷꣻꣽꣾꤊ-ꤥꤰ-ꥆꥠ-ꥼꦄ-ꦲꧏꧠ-ꧤꧦ-ꧯꧺ-ꧾꨀ-ꨨꩀ-ꩂꩄ-ꩋꩠ-ꩶꩺꩾ-ꪯꪱꪵꪶꪹ-ꪽꫀꫂꫛ-ꫝꫠ-ꫪꫲ-ꫴꬁ-ꬆꬉ-ꬎꬑ-ꬖꬠ-ꬦꬨ-ꬮꬰ-ꭚꭜ-ꭩꭰ-ꯢ가-힣ힰ-ퟆퟋ-ퟻ豈-舘並-龎ﬀ-ﬆﬓ-ﬗיִײַ-ﬨשׁ-זּטּ-לּמּנּסּףּפּצּ-ﮱﯓ-ﴽﵐ-ﶏﶒ-ﷇﷰ-ﷻﹰ-ﹴﹶ-ﻼＡ-Ｚａ-ｚｦ-ﾾￂ-ￇￊ-ￏￒ-ￗￚ-ￜ",n="‌‍·̀-ͯ·҃-֑҇-ׇֽֿׁׂׅׄؐ-ًؚ-٩ٰۖ-ۜ۟-۪ۤۧۨ-ۭ۰-۹ܑܰ-݊ަ-ް߀-߉߫-߽߳ࠖ-࠙ࠛ-ࠣࠥ-ࠧࠩ-࡙࠭-࡛࢘-࢟࣊-ࣣ࣡-ःऺ-़ा-ॏ॑-ॗॢॣ०-९ঁ-ঃ়া-ৄেৈো-্ৗৢৣ০-৯৾ਁ-ਃ਼ਾ-ੂੇੈੋ-੍ੑ੦-ੱੵઁ-ઃ઼ા-ૅે-ૉો-્ૢૣ૦-૯ૺ-૿ଁ-ଃ଼ା-ୄେୈୋ-୍୕-ୗୢୣ୦-୯ஂா-ூெ-ைொ-்ௗ௦-௯ఀ-ఄ఼ా-ౄె-ైొ-్ౕౖౢౣ౦-౯ಁ-ಃ಼ಾ-ೄೆ-ೈೊ-್ೕೖೢೣ೦-೯ഀ-ഃ഻഼ാ-ൄെ-ൈൊ-്ൗൢൣ൦-൯ඁ-ඃ්ා-ුූෘ-ෟ෦-෯ෲෳัิ-ฺ็-๎๐-๙ັິ-ຼ່-ໍ໐-໙༘༙༠-༩༹༵༷༾༿ཱ-྄྆྇ྍ-ྗྙ-ྼ࿆ါ-ှ၀-၉ၖ-ၙၞ-ၠၢ-ၤၧ-ၭၱ-ၴႂ-ႍႏ-ႝ፝-፟፩-፱ᜒ-᜕ᜲ-᜴ᝒᝓᝲᝳ឴-៓៝០-៩᠋-᠍᠏-᠙ᢩᤠ-ᤫᤰ-᤻᥆-᥏᧐-᧚ᨗ-ᨛᩕ-ᩞ᩠-᩿᩼-᪉᪐-᪙᪰-᪽ᪿ-ᫎᬀ-ᬄ᬴-᭄᭐-᭙᭫-᭳ᮀ-ᮂᮡ-ᮭ᮰-᮹᯦-᯳ᰤ-᰷᱀-᱉᱐-᱙᳐-᳔᳒-᳨᳭᳴᳷-᳹᷀-᷿‿⁀⁔⃐-⃥⃜⃡-⃰⳯-⵿⳱ⷠ-〪ⷿ-゙゚〯꘠-꘩꙯ꙴ-꙽ꚞꚟ꛰꛱ꠂ꠆ꠋꠣ-ꠧ꠬ꢀꢁꢴ-ꣅ꣐-꣙꣠-꣱ꣿ-꤉ꤦ-꤭ꥇ-꥓ꦀ-ꦃ꦳-꧀꧐-꧙ꧥ꧰-꧹ꨩ-ꨶꩃꩌꩍ꩐-꩙ꩻ-ꩽꪰꪲ-ꪴꪷꪸꪾ꪿꫁ꫫ-ꫯꫵ꫶ꯣ-ꯪ꯬꯭꯰-꯹ﬞ︀-️︠-︯︳︴﹍-﹏０-９＿",o=new RegExp("["+r+"]"),a=new RegExp("["+r+n+"]");r=n=null;var i=[0,11,2,25,2,18,2,1,2,14,3,13,35,122,70,52,268,28,4,48,48,31,14,29,6,37,11,29,3,35,5,7,2,4,43,157,19,35,5,35,5,39,9,51,13,10,2,14,2,6,2,1,2,10,2,14,2,6,2,1,68,310,10,21,11,7,25,5,2,41,2,8,70,5,3,0,2,43,2,1,4,0,3,22,11,22,10,30,66,18,2,1,11,21,11,25,71,55,7,1,65,0,16,3,2,2,2,28,43,28,4,28,36,7,2,27,28,53,11,21,11,18,14,17,111,72,56,50,14,5
```

Is there anyone who has already stumbled upon this behavior?

Comment: Weird. Seems more like a naughty browser extension to me. What happens if you use your application in a browser with all extensions disabled / incognito?

Comment: I tried with `chrome` and `firefox`, and also in `ingognito`: nothing changed: the `iframe` is always there"

Comment: Are you using a yaml file or another deployment path for this? cause it have no sense to get the iframe from nothing.

Comment: No, I don't. I'm running `VSC` in debug mode with the code inspector open to see the iframe.

Comment: Understood, can you include more detail on the section where you are using Google Login in GCP?

Comment: Got the exact same problem

Comment: I have the same problem,
Solution here
[https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
npm i -D react-error-overlay@6.0.9
```

Basically this iframe appeared when it found some kind of compiling error.

in my case the error is like
[image]

https://postimg.cc/gn3Q8mdH

without react-error-overlay@6.0.9 the overlay appeared with transparent text & background so we can not see that.

After run "npm i -D react-error-overlay@6.0.9" reload and this time the overlay shows the error with exact text and now just fixed the error. and the site will run perfectly.